# Unable to install third party bundles through composer in symfony 3

Tags: symfony

i am new in Symfony 3.Can you please suggest me how to install third party bundles in symfony 3. I was using the command. from the root directory of my project File_Sym..

$ composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle

And got the error

pc11@pc11-ThinkCentre-E73:~/File_Sym$ composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
No command 'composer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'compose' from package 'mime-support' (main)
composer: command not found

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't actually have composer installed (unless it requires sudo command - let me know if that's the case), so you'll have to install it.
Read this link:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

once you install, run the command:

```
composer
```

to verify that it is installed correctly.

Comment: Hi Sandeep. You should click the up arrow and checkmark on my answer then. The checkmark indicates the correct answer, the up arrow means it was helpful. Thanks! Glad you got it working!